# Image path issue

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

I have several images in css files and js files and we ASP.Net MVC.
After deploying in the server images are getting loaded from the path
http://example.com/Images/image.png, whereas the actual is in http://example.com/mysite/Images/image.png

I have tried several paths
like 
/Images/image.png

../Images/image.png

Images/image.png

../../Images/image.png.

However browser always tries to load it from the Images folder directly under the domain which does not exist.

Comment: Did you set a base URL in some type of a page template?

Comment: Where is located your CSS?

Comment: How are you referencing to the location of your css / images files? Please post your code

Comment: If your root changes between environments, you should use Url helpers, like: src='@Url.Content("~/Contents/IMages/image.png")'

Comment: i cannot use a url helper since these are external css and javascript files.For all the images in the cshtml i have used url hepers and they are rendered correctly.

Comment: Confused, if they are external then you should be providing the whole path

Answer (score 0):

Let say that you have following structure
MySite

MySite\Content\CSS\styles.css

MySite\Content\Images\img1.png

**In styles.css**

```
.myheader{
   background-image:url('../Images/img1.png');
}
```

OR

**In layout.cshtml** or **index.cshtml**

```
<div style="background-image:url('@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/img1.png")');"></div>
```

OR

```
<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/img1.png")' />
```

one thing you have to make sure that it path is **case-sensitive**

I am using these tricks in my projects.

I hope it will help you.